# Restore database SQL Server linux

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, ssms

I am restore database sql server in linux and i have problem with the path, thing. My version of Sql Server is 2019 and version is develop.

I use:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [prueba] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/cliente.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
```

And the output is:

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server myserver, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "F:\DATA\balmaceda\cliente.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server myserver, Line 1
File 'cliente' cannot be restored to 'F:\DATA\balmaceda\cliente.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server myserver, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "F:\LOG\cliente\cliente_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server myserver, Line 1
File 'cliente_log' cannot be restored to 'F:\LOG\cliente\cliente_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server myserver, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server myserver, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Did you read the error messages? `Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.`

Comment: *"cannot be restored to 'F:\DATA\balmaceda\cliente.mdf'."* Well no... That's not a valid Unix (like) path.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the response in: [DBeaver restore SQL Server .bak file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257965/dbeaver-restore-sql-server-bak-file)

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [prueba2] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/cliente.bak' WITH MOVE 'cliente' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/cliente.mdf', MOVE 'cliente' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/cliente.ldf'"
```